# xPages repeat control with pager issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, xpages

The pager is being reset to position #1 while navigating. It seems the page is being refreshed at some point so it resets the pager. I cannot figure out what's going on. Try to work with large view. Does it loads all views documents again when you click on the pager? How to fix it? It happens regardless of pager property "partialRefresh" (true or false)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="MyView">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" partialRefresh="true"
        id="pager1" for="repeat1">
    </xp:pager>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="5" value="#{view1}" var="collName"
        indexVar="collIndex">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:collName.getColumnValues()[3]}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

This is what I see after the click that resets the pager to #1:
[image]

Comment: Your example works fine for me. No fallback to page #1. Did you test it with exact this code?

Comment: yes.. exact this code.. Try to click more than 10 times but not #1.. Then at some time it will switch to 1# automatically that I don't want to happen. Does repeat loads/refresh data every time you click pager? That maybe the case

Comment: Nope. I clicked through to page 1001 and never fall back to page #1. I set session and application timeout to one minute and waited but still worked fine.

Comment: Yes, repeat control loads/refreshes data every time I click pager. But, only the five rows and the pager itself as it contains the changing page numbers. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: is it possible that the source view got more documents so that refresh recalculates page numbers and reset it to #1?

Comment: At the click it resets the pager I saw "Connection: "close" in FireFox console. See picture above..

Comment: Is there a chance someone messes with application design? Build, refresh from template, replication, signing database...?

Comment: Nobody have access. I build/clean it everytime I put my changes

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to use Extension Library pager that works much better